# Deque via two vectors C++

Tags: c++, deque

I am taking a course of C++ and stacked on the task.
I tried to implement deque via two vectors on C++ but my realization is too slow. I think slowness causes by PushFront function. Implementation is correct (i think so), the only problem is slowness.
Give me some advices to make my solution faster, please :)

```
template<typename T>
class Deque{
public:    
    Deque(){}    

    const bool Empty() const{
        return first.empty() && second.empty();
    }

    const size_t Size() const{
        return first.size() + second.size();
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index){
        if (index < first.size()){
            return first[index];
        }
        else if (index < first.size() + second.size()){
            return second[index - first.size()];
        }
        else{
            throw out_of_range("index out of range");
        }
    }

    const T& operator[](size_t index) const{
        if (index < first.size()){
            return first[index];
        }
        else if (index < first.size() + second.size()){
            return second[index - first.size()];
        }
        else{
            throw out_of_range("index out of range");
        }
    }

    const T& At(size_t index) const{
        if (index < first.size()){
            return first[index];
        }
        else if (index < first.size() + second.size()){
            return second[index - first.size()];
        }
        else{
            throw out_of_range("index out of range");
        }
    }

    T& At(size_t index){
        if (index < first.size()){
            return first[index];
        }
        else if (index < first.size() + second.size()){
            return second[index - first.size()];
        }
        else{
            throw out_of_range("index out of range");
        }
    }

    T& Front(){
        if (first.empty() && second.empty())
            throw out_of_range("out of range");
        else if (first.empty() && !second.empty())
            return second[0];
        else
            return first[0];
    }

    const T& Front() const{
        if (first.empty() && second.empty())
            throw out_of_range("out of range");
        else if (first.empty() && !second.empty())
            return second[0];
        else
            return first[0];
    }


    T& Back(){
        if (second.empty() && first.empty())
            throw out_of_range("out of range");
        else if (second.empty() && !first.empty())
            return first[first.size() - 1];
        else
            return second[second.size() - 1];
    }

    const T& Back() const{
        if (second.empty() && first.empty())
            throw out_of_range("out of range");
        else if (second.empty() && !first.empty())
            return first[first.size() - 1];
        else
            return second[second.size() - 1];
    }

    void PushFront(const T& elem){
        first.insert(first.begin(), elem);
    }

    void PushBack(const T& elem) {
        second.push_back(elem);
    }

private:
    vector<T> first, second;
};
```

Comment: How slow is too slow? Have you enabled compiler optimisations?

Comment: If you only have two vectors then push_front is always going to be slow. You should use a list of vectors, so that when the first vector gets too big, you can just create a new vector and add it to the beginning of the list.

Comment: Does the course say that you have to use vectors, or is it your choice? Other containers might be more appropriate: https://john-ahlgren.blogspot.com/2013/10/stl-container-performance.html Inserting at the front is O(n), because you basically have to "make room" for the new zero element and move all of the other elements. `push_back` can be O(1) in case the vector still has free allocated capacity, or can be expanded at the current location.

Comment: You should also deduplicate your code to make it more maintainable. Currently most access methods are just copied and pasted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I can't use <list> <set> or <map>. And I have to use vectors due to the task's conditions.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I just send my solution to testing system and It returns Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Do you mean to call in body of non-const functions const functions?

Comment: I was thinking that `operator[]` is the same as `At`. But this is secondary, since your primary concern seems to be performance.

Comment: @Din One idea could be to allocate a vector with higher capacity, and start inserting elements in the middle. Another way would be to have a vector of pairs <int, vector>, where the int denotes whether the vector is at the front or back, and it's index and "direction". Then you can just push_back elements to the "inner" vectors, and the index tells you the iteration direction (i.e. whether it is front or back). That can make insertion O(1), depending on capacity.